# propriedade com List de Objetos em Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Tenho as seguintes classes:

```
public class objeto1
{
   public string Descricao {get;set;}
   public List<objeto2> Objeto2 {get;set}
}

public class objeto2
{
   public string Descricao {get;set}
   public decimal Valor {get;set}
}
```

Estou usando o **Crystal Reports** e gostaria de usar a classe do  **objeto1** para construir um relatório. Assim, poderei enviar uma lista de **objeto1** e fazer a leitura no **Crystal Reports**.

O problema é que eu só consigo visualizar a propriedade **Descricao** do **objeto1**, mas não consigo acessar a **List** de **objeto2** no **Database Fields**.

Vale ressaltar que é a primeira vez que uso o CR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não teve como usar os Objetos dessa forma. O jeito foi criar uma nova propriedade para cada um com um `Id`, então no Cristal Reports posso fazer um link entre eles.

```
public class objeto1
{
   public int Id {get;set}
   public string Descricao {get;set;}
}

public class objeto2
{
   public int IddoPai {get;set}
   public string Descricao {get;set}
   public decimal Valor {get;set}
}
```

Assim, pude passar para o Crystal Reports o `objeto1` e uma lista de `objeto2`.